# ngFor to populate options on a drop-down from key value object in Angular 2

Tags: angular

How use ngFor to populate options on a drop-down from key value object in Angular 2. json is below.

```
   {
     "employment": {
      "0": "Employed",
      "2": "Un-employed",
      "3": "Retired",
      "4": "Self"
      "V": "V"
   },
    "citizenship": {
      "0": "Citizen",
      "1": "Immigrant",
      "2": "Visa",
    },
    "phone": {
      "HOME": "Home",
      "CELL": "Cell",
      "WORK": "Work"
    }
```

I need to populate options for 3 dropdowns for employment , phone and immigration using ngfor. Angular 2

Comment: {
  "employment": {
    "0": "Employed",
    "2": "Un-employed",
    "3": "Retired",
    "4": "Self"
  },
  "citizenship": {
    "0": "Citizen",
    "1": "Immigrant",
    "2": "Visa"
  },
  "phone": {
    "HOME": "Home",
    "CELL": "Cell",
    "WORK": "Work"
  }
}

Answer (score 2):

So you have to render 3 dropdowns based on three following objects:

```
obj.employment
obj.citizenship
obj.phone
```

where `obj` is

```
var obj = {
   "employment":{
      "0":"Employed",
      "2":"Un-employed",
      "3":"Retired",
      "4":"Self"
   },
   "citizenship":{
      "0":"Citizen",
      "1":"Immigrant",
      "2":"Visa"
   },
   "phone":{
      "HOME":"Home",
      "CELL":"Cell",
      "WORK":"Work"
   }
}
```

I found a link on the internet and think this is exactly what you want

[Looping Over Object Properties in Angular 2’s ngFor](https://webcake.co/object-properties-in-angular-2s-ngfor/)

Note: You should return the same format for `phone` property as `employment` or `citizenship`

Comment: link broken - should copy example here to avoid broken links

Answer (score 0):

> Hope this helps you

```
const obj = {
        employment: [
            { Id: 0, text: 'Employed' },
            { Id: 1, text: 'Un-employed' },
            { Id: 2, text: 'Retired' },
            { Id: 3, text: 'Self' }
        ],
        citizenship: [
            { Id: 0, text: 'Citizen' },
            { Id: 1, text: 'Immigrant' },
            { Id: 2, text: 'Visa' },
        ],
        phone: [
            { Id: 0, text: 'Home' },
            { Id: 1, text: 'Cell' },
            { Id: 2, text: 'Work' }
        ]
    }
```

and user as

```
user = { employmentId: 0, citizenshipId: 1, phone: 'work'};
```

**use in template as**

```
 <select class="form-control" name="employment" #employment="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.employmentId" required > 
    <option value="" [disabled] selected>Employment</option>
    <option  *ngFor="let emp of obj.employment" [value]="emp.Id" [innerHTML]="emp.text" ></option>
 </select>

 <select class="form-control" name="citizenship" #citizenship="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.citizenshipId" required > 
    <option value="" [disabled] selected>Citizenship</option>
    <option  *ngFor="let citizen of obj.citizenship" [value]="citizen.Id" [innerHTML]="citizen.text" ></option>
 </select>

 <select class="form-control" name="phone" #phone="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.phone" required > 
    <option value="" [disabled] selected>Phone</option>
    <option  *ngFor="let num of obj.phone" [value]="num.Id" [innerHTML]="num.text" ></option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Thank you but json object should be key value pair not id and text